# Extending searchResultsTableView with a category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-category

## import "UITableView+hideSeparators.h"

I have made a category for UITableView. This allows me to hide the separators on it, however my understanding is that importing this category makes all UITableView in the file with the import have the method?

```
[self hideSeparators];
```

This works but

```
[[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] hideSeparators];
```

Produces

```
No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'hideSeparators'
```

Why does the category apply to the TableView but not to the searchResultsTableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a category for hiding separators? Why you couldn't just try something

```
[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView].separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Comment: Ah, certainly. However, that is not really the core problem here, I thought I misunderstood how categories work and want to clear up this scenario so I can understand how they work.

Comment: Well I guess that warning you've received is caused because you don't have your category included in UITableView.h file of course. You might wanna check out official docs for [Categories and Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

Comment: I know about the official docs. I have #import "UITableView+hideSeparators.h" in the header file. I tried to convey this in my question, but it turned out as a big title at the top because it removed the leading spaces. But what do you mean with "UITableView.h" Where would this file be? The crux is that the first line works and not the second. Both are UITableView. I thought all of them got the extension.